# .net Core 3.1 - First page ask language then redirect to a page

Tags: c#, .net, endpoint, .net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-middleware

I am new to .net core and willing to have a easy stuff.

First web page opened ([www.mypage.com](http://www.mypage.com)) I would like to ask language in empty page with selection which language will be. Then redirect to page [www.mypage.com/en](http://www.mypage.com/en) or any other culture.
The point is clearly once it is selected, It can read from cookies that it has a language and opened in with the format of [www.mypage.com/en](http://www.mypage.com/en) or the other

I am lost while I was surfing to find an easy answer...

Wishing It will have an easy answer

Thanks

My registered routes

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{culture=es}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        
        endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "admin",
            pattern: "{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
```

Comment: Can you explain what means `It can read from cookies that it has a language and opened in with the format of www.mypage.com/en or the other`

Comment: https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/globalization-and-localization-in-aspnet-core/  -----The adress That I took the code and It adds the language info into cookie. Also The default lang is settled in endpoints. All I want is to create a landing page that ask which language and redirect to www.mypage.com/{language}  @Yinqiu